# How to enable hardware acceleration of video decoding in mplayer with Intel HD3000 on Vivid?

Tags: video, 15.04, video-player, mplayer, vaapi

There [used to be a vaapi build of mplayer](https://launchpad.net/~sander-vangrieken/+archive/ubuntu/vaapi) but it doesn't seem to be maintained any more and doesn't work in Vivid.

Default mplayer2 build from the repo uses 40% of CPU during 720p playback. Same as totem. VLC does have some hardware acceleration support and uses 13% but I liked mplayer's UI more and it used less than 5% with.

Is it currently possible to use mplayer with hardware acceleration on Intel integrated graphics?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, I found `mpv` (a fork of mplayer) which does everything I wanted and carried all the good UI qualities from mplayer2.

To enable vaapi support, run it with `mpv --vo=opengl-hq --hwdec=vaapi file.mkv`

or add

```
vo=opengl-hq
hwdec=vaapi
```

to  `~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf`.

Previously the answer suggested using vo=vaapi and hwdec=vaapi but this is not a recommended setup anymore. See comments.

Comment: mpv works really well, thank you for sharing your solution. On my system, setting "hwdec=auto" is sufficient to get accelerated playback; supposedly, vo=opengl is better than vo=vaapi on newer systems: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mpv#Hardware_Decoding

Comment: I switched `vo=opengl-hq` with `hwdec=vaapi` which is what they seem to recommend.

Comment: FTR: I noticed that `hwdec=vaapi` doesn't seem to work for me *(i.e. eats to much cpu)*, but `--hwdec=vaapi` option does work. mpv-0.3.4.

Answer (score -2):

`SNA` is the best acceleration method. You should check your config file if you have one. Another way is to renice the process. For example:

```
ps ax|grep mplayer
```

find the given process and renice it

```
renice -20 43332
```

You can do it as root only (maybe it is possible with sudo: `sudo renice -20 43332` ).

Comment: What does `SNA` do? How do I enable it?

Comment: SNA is a better acceleration than any other. You probably won't have `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.  `EXA`, `UXA` are older acceleration methods. Yous check what acceleration method are you using. You can probably do it by `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log|egrep -i EXA|UXA|SNA`

Comment: Yes. My system does seem to support it `SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.917-1~exp1ubuntu2build1`. How can I make use of it in mplayer?

Comment: It's using it automatically. :) Could you, please, give us the output of `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log|egrep -i "EXA|UXA|SNA"` ? And the output of `cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf` ?

Comment: But it clearly isn't. `Mplayer` uses 40-60% cpu when playing a video where `mpv` uses only 7. There is no xorg.conf, [here are the outputs](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/73ff1b70098252daf9c1).

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with that. You are using SNA, that's good to hear. I didn't know about `mpv`, thanks for that anyway :)

Comment: SNA is used for accelerated X11 drawing and has nothing to do with (hardware accelerated) video decoding.